# Android get element group by id then select by tag

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a table view in which i populate rows via xml like this 
TableLayout table= (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblLayoutPop);

```
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        TableRow row = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(Popup.this).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        row.setTag(i);
        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.header)).setText("Some Text");
        EditText ed= (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ed.setTag(i);
        Button add= (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        add.setTag(i);
        Button remove= (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonRemove);
        remove.setTag(i);
        table.addView(row);
    }
```

And xml is [here](http://pastebin.com/VaJmdWRU) looks like [image]

There are 3 such rows , now on click of add button i want to increment its particular edit text

For this i tried this , to select edit text first then get it by tag

```
public void add(View v){
        String tag = v.getTag().toString();
        Log.d("TAG", tag);
        int position = Integer.parseInt(tag);

        View eds= findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText ed= (EditText) eds.findViewWithTag(position);
        ed.setText(tag);
    }
```

this doesnt work And I need a way to select corresponding edit text. How to do this

Any help is really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a look at ur xml file

First thing change your edit text's tag to something different from buttons

like `ed.setTag("ed"+i);`

Then u can select edit text via tag from parent view of button. As u have already grouped buttons and edit text in linear layout.

Like this

```
EditText ed= (EditText) ((View) v.getParent()).findViewWithTag("ed"+tag);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but it may point you to the right direction

```
implement View.OnClickListener
```

in your loop set click event to your Button Views

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    TableRow row = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(Popup.this).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    row.setTag(i);
    ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.header)).setText("Some Text");
    EditText ed= (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed.setTag(i);
    Button add= (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    add.setTag(i);
    add.setOnClickListener(this)
    Button remove= (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonRemove);
    remove.setTag(i);
    remove.setOnClickListener(this);
    table.addView(row);
}
```

then in your `onClick(View view)` method, try this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int viewId = view.getId();

    if(viewId == R.id.buttonAdd && view.getTag().toString().equals("0")){
        View parentView = view.getRootView();
        EditText mEditText = (EditText)parentView.findViewWithTag("0");

        int currentEditTextValue = Integer.parseInt(mEditText.getText().toString());
        currentEditTextValue = currentEditTextValue + 1;
        mEditText.setText(String.valueOf(currentEditTextValue));
    }
    // more conditions here ...
}
```

Hope it gives you more ideas. Do ask question if you have any.

Comment: Thanks @Nolly J but as i see i vl end up with 3 conditions based on `view.getTag().toString().equals("0")` then `view.getTag().toString().equals("1")` and so on , if i have n rows then n conditions, may be check them in for loop , not a very efficient approach. And i just copy pasted it and it crashes at this line `int currentEditTextValue = Integer.parseInt(mEditText.getText().toString());`